# FlexMojos - Runtime error - VerifyError #1014 mx.controls.List Class not Found

Tags: maven, apache-flex, flex4.5, verifyerror, flexmojos

I'm using FlexMojos 4.0-RC2 and Flex SDK 4.5.1 to compile my app which consists of several modules.

The compilation is sucessful with insignificant warnings.

When I try to run the application I get a VerifyError #1014 saying that mx.controls.List is not found.

I tried several other things.....

turning modulesLoadExterns to either true or false, setting static link runtime shared libraries to true, false, adding the swf version tag....

I'm not really sure what else I can do to resolve the issue....

${target.flash.player.version} is 10.0

Below is the flexmojo configuration I'm using...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-RC2</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <sourceFile>FundsFlexApp.mxml</sourceFile>
                <contextRoot>funds</contextRoot>
                <targetPlayer>${target.flash.player.version}</targetPlayer>
                <services>${basedir}/target/generated-resources/services-config.xml</services>
                <themes>
                    <theme>
                        ${settings.localRepository}/com/adobe/flex/framework/framework/${flex.sdk.version}/framework-${flex.sdk.version}-configs/themes/halo/halo.swc
                    </theme>
                </themes>
                <modules>
                    <module>CounterpartyMaintenanceModule.mxml</module>
                    <module>ManageProposedLimitsModule.mxml</module>
                    <module>NavUploadModule.mxml</module>
                </modules>
                <defines>
                    <property>
                        <name>CONFIG::debugging</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>CONFIG::buildTimeStamp</name>
                        <value>'${maven.build.timestamp}'</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>CONFIG::versionNumber</name>
                        <value>'${project.build.version}'</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>CONFIG::fundsModuleUrl</name>
                        <value>'${funds.module.url}'</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>CONFIG::fundsEndpointUrl</name>
                        <value>'${funds.endpoint.url}'</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>CONFIG::excelExportEndpointUrl</name>
                        <value>'${funds.excelexport.url}'</value>
                    </property>
                </defines>
                <debug>${flex.debug}</debug>
                <storepass/>
                <linkReportAttach>true</linkReportAttach>
                <allowSourcePathOverlap>true</allowSourcePathOverlap>
                <headlessServer>true</headlessServer>
                <localesCompiled>
                    <locale>en_US</locale>
                </localesCompiled>
                <keepGeneratedActionscript>true</keepGeneratedActionscript>
                <includeSources>
                    <source>${basedir}/src/main/flex</source>
                </includeSources>
                <as3>true</as3>
                <flashPlayerCommand>flashplayer</flashPlayerCommand>
                <modulesLoadExterns>false</modulesLoadExterns>
                <staticLinkRuntimeSharedLibraries>true</staticLinkRuntimeSharedLibraries>
                <strict>true</strict>
                <swfVersion>11</swfVersion>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <templates>
                            <base-bean-template>${basedir}/src/main/templates/beanBaseBlaze.gsp</base-bean-template>
                        </templates>
                        <includeJavaClasses>
                            <includeClass>...different classes....
                            </includeClass>
                        </includeJavaClasses>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                    <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>${flex.sdk.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId>
                    <version>${flex.sdk.version}</version>
                    <type>swc</type>
                    <classifier>${flash.player.classifier}</classifier>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${flex.sdk.license.groupid}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>license</artifactId>
                    <version>${flex.sdk.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the "theme" configuration from FlexMojos and moving to the "theme" scoped dependency? Please see the following discussion (on Stackoverflow) for background:

[How to define a new kind of scope in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918709/how-to-define-a-new-kind-of-scope-in-maven)

Comment: yes, I've solved the problem. One of the libraries was loaded as an external library when it shouldn't have been.